# pppd options not working with sstpc to add default route?

Tags: networking, vpn, ppp

I am using vpnazure sstp service on my Ubuntu laptop. I can establish the connection using sstpc command which looks like `sudo sstpc --log-stderr --log-level 2 --cert-warn --tls-ext --user user --password pass host.vpnazure.net usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault defaultroute refuse-eap noccp`.

In my case, pppd opion `defaultroute` is not working. I have checked the routing table with `route -n`. I can tell there's no default route added for the sstp connection. There's even no route to the sstp network. I have to manually add the route to the sstp network and then the default route. My system is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64, and sstp-client's version is 1.0.11-0ubuntu1.

I've tried same command line on my MacBook which is working fine for the default route. No log entry found in syslog.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pppd` probably did not add route to direct all traffic to the VPN interface (say, `ppp0`). You can check the name of the VPN interface by this cmd `ifconfig`. After successfully running the `sstpc` command, you will see an extra interface (normally `ppp0`). Now you can try running this command to force all traffic of your machine go through the VPN interface:

```
route add default ppp0
```

Hope this help.